# HyperLink in MVC View-ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a value in an variable(MVC View). This value has to be passed to the stored procedure parameter.

The URL of Report hosted on Different box is:

http://differentbox/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fMyReports%2fReport1.

This reports needs a stored procedure, The value for the stored procedure should go from the MVC View.(The Value is available in a variable)

I want to Place a hyperlink on a MVC View, so that clicking on it will take the value from the MVC and stored procedure will run.

Any ideas please, I am looking for the approach of how to pass the value from VIEW to Stored Procedure.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an action link with the parameter in the querystring. Otherwise use a reporting services webservice like suggested here: [Executing Reporting Services Web Service from ASP.NET MVC Using WCF](http://geekswithblogs.net/stun/archive/2010/02/26/executing-reporting-services-web-service-from-asp-net-mvc-using-wcf-add-service-reference.aspx)

**Answer updated**

Just add an `<a href='blah'>` tag with the link pointing to your Reporting Services server.

To call a reporting services with a parameter use the SRSS R2 request as follow:
http://differentbox/Reportserver?/MyReports/Report1&rs:Command=Render&paramname=value

Answer (score 0):

Do async call with jquery, and send the parameter to your controller based on the view.
Save the variable in hidden field and then send it.

In the view:

```
var dataToSend = $("#(ID of the hidden with the value)").val();
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action(actionName, controllerName)',
    type: "POST",
    data: {data : dataToSend },
   dataType: "json"
```

});

controller:

```
 public void actionName(object data)
 {
     // Do what ever you want with the data.
 }
```